# Using H2-database with microservices and API Gateway

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices, h2, api-gateway

I am trying to build a microservice architecture using spring boot. I have to add H2-Database to it. I am also using an API gateway in between the services to fetch respective data. Not sure how to configure API gateway with h2-database.

Here is what lies in my application.properties file for all of the microservcies, except for API Gateway.

```
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=username
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:socialdb
```